# what is difference between 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3' and 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying update latest gradle android plugin. I have tried with '3.0.0-alpha1' initially and now I am using'3.0.0-alpha3'.

With '3.0.0-alpha1' version, I got an error 'not found' and after that I  switched to '3.0.0-alpha3', with that I got below error.

Error :- 'getMainOutputFile is no longer supported.  Use getOutputFileName if you need to determine the file name of the output'.

I fixed that error also.

But , I just want to what is the difference between '3.0.0-alpha1' and '3.0.0-alpha3', Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best info I could find was [Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3 is now available](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-3-is-now.html)

> We have just released Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3 to the Canary and Dev Channels. The Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0-alpha3 was also released through maven.google.com. This release has fixes to Gradle, Kotlin, and many other fixes. We continue to fix bugs in all areas of Studio 3.0 as we stabilize our features, so please continue to pass on feedback.

And from [Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2 is now available](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-30-canary-2-is-now.html)

> We have just released Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2 to the Canary and Dev channels. The Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0-alpha2 was also released through maven.google.com.
>
> This release includes fixes focused on:
>
> - Kotlin support
> - APK Analyzer
> - Android Profilers
> - Android Instant Apps
> - Android Gradle plugin
> - Native / C++ Issues
> - and general bug fixes

You might try searching the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192708%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc) for your specific issues too.

Comment: Thank you.. This is very useful info.